# Error Call to undefined method stdClass::volunteers() when trying to sync a pivot table

Tags: php, laravel

I have a pivot table, I am trying to sync that table but it keeps throwing a `FatalError: Call to undefined method stdClass:: volunteers()`, I am working with PHP7 and Laravel5.

My Controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    ........

        $show = DB::table(Config::get('constants.tables.ShowsTable'))
        ->where(Config::get('constants.fields.ShowsIdField'), $id)
        ->first();

        if(!empty($request -> volunteer_id)){
                $show -> volunteers() 
                -> sync($request -> volunteer_id);
        }

            ............
```

My Model:

```
class Show extends Model {

     protected $table = 'shows';

     protected $fillable = ['name','description','schedule','image'];

     public function volunteers(){
        return $this -> belongsToMany('App\Volunteer')
        ->withTimestamps();
     }
   }
```

Migrartion:

```
Schema::create('show_volunteer',function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->integer('show_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('volunteer_id')->unsigned();

        $table->primary(['show_id', 'volunteer_id']);
        $table->foreign('show_id')->references('show_id')
        ->on('shows')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('volunteer_id')->references('volunteer_id')
        ->on('volunteers')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->timestamps();
});
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$show` is a result set not a instance of `Model` class.

You can use the `hydrate()` function.

```
$myModel = Show::hydrate($show);
$myModel->volunteers()->sync($request -> volunteer_id);
```

Maybe you will need to point to index zero. Not sure though.

Or you can use Eloquent from the beginning, instead of `DB::table`